# bash prompt coloring for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, git, bash, command-prompt

### The Goal

I'm trying to colorize my bash prompt on Mac OS X with the git branch (where available).

### What I've Tried

With my limited bash knowledge, I pieced together the following code from Google searches and other questions:

```
function parse_git_branch() {
        branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)

        if [[ -z "$branch" ]]; then
                return
        fi

        if [[ -z "$(git status -s 2>/dev/null)" ]]; then
                color=$'\e[1;32m'
        else
                color=$'\e[1;31m'
        fi

        echo "\[$color\] (${branch}) "
}

PS1="\h:\W \u\$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[0m\]\$ "
```

### The Problem

While the coloration works, the prompt contains some of the escape sequences from `parse_git_branch`.

```
leonidas:AYI jason\[\] (master) $
```

In addition, things like command history (up) and recursive search (ctrl+r) yield extra characters.

```
leonidas:AYI jason\[\] (master) $h)`re': git status
```

### The Questions

1. How can I fix the escaping with proper visible and non-visible characters.
2. Should I use `tput` instead of these color codes for wider support?

Comment: (1) switch to [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/), (2) get [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), (3) [choose a theme](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes), (4) never look back!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, thanks for the suggestion. But I'd like to solve the current problem.

Comment: @Kevin, Could you provide more information - where, why?

Comment: When you set `PS1="...$(parse_git_branch)..."`, it is evaluated precisely once, while sourcing the file. You need `PS1='...'` to have it evaluated every time.

Comment: @Kevin, that's not the problem I am having. It is evaluated every time.

Answer (score 3):

Why go to all this trouble. Just create a `.bash_profile`
Mine is:-

```
export PS1="\[\033[0;30;33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]$ "
```

You should set `.bashrc` to reference this

```
[ -r ~/.bash_profile ] && source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: See my update, I'm trying to include the git branch (if available).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\[ \]` is not respected in expanded data.

To get around it, you can set PS1 to a post-expansion version of itself in `PROMPT_COMMAND`, whose contents is evaluated before every prompt:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="\h:\W \u$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[0m\]\\\$ "'
```

Since the `\[ \]` are now part of the literal value of PS1, and not created by prompt expansion, they're correctly interpretted.

Comment: yup. Simpler example: `ps1() { echo '\h:\W$ '; };  PS1='$(ps1)';`  Your prompt will be literally `\h:\W$ `.

Comment: While I will try this, it feels *hackish* to me. There must be a way to *fix* what I have.